# Reporting Fixed Effects as (partial) correlations?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, reporting, partial-correlation

I'm doing a linear mixed effects analysis in which I'm really only interested in one of the fixed effects. I have several other fixed effects and a random intercept term, but none of them are relevant, nor is the overall goodness-of-fit of the model (other than the fact that adding my regressor of interest (ROI) improves it significantly).

So, I now want to report the size of my interesting fixed effect in an intuitive way. In a simple multiple regression analysis, I would compute the partial correlation between my ROI and the outcome measure by regressing out all other factors from both the ROI and the outcome measure, and then computing the correlation between the residuals from these two "nuisance regressions". Or, equivalently, taking the beta coefficient on the ROI and multiplying it by the ratio of the standard deviations of the residuals from the nuisance regressions, i.e. SD(ROI_res)/SD(Outcome_res).

I would like to do something similar here (with linear mixed effects), but I have trouble finding the right approach. Certainly, just "copy-pasting" the approach from multiple regression doesn't seem to yield sensible results (as the 2 ways of doing this which were previously equivalent now give different answers). So all of this boils down to 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to obtain partial correlation coefficients for fixed effects in a linear mixed model?

2) If not, then what would be appropriate way to report my effect of interest? Reporting the estimated fixed effect coefficient seems valid but not very insightful in terms of effect size/strength of association (as it is entirely dependent on the scale of the two variables), so my guess is there should be a better way...

Comment: the [performance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/performance/performance.pdf) package in R  can measure "conditional R2" (random & fixed effects together), "marginal R2" (random effect alone), adjusted ICC (fixed effect alone) & "conditional ICC" (fixed effect controlling by random effect).
The theory behind it is in this paper:
Nakagawa, S., Johnson, P. C., & Schielzeth, H. (2017). The coefficient of determination R 2 and intra-class correlation coefficient from generalized linear mixed-effects models revisited and expanded. Journal of the Royal Society Interface, 14(134), 2017021